# Define a route to start with specific string in asp.net core 2.1 startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I implemented a route with this structure is startup file

```
routes.MapRoute(
 name: "myroute",
 template: "{id:length(8)}",
 defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "myAction" });
```

this route sends requests to `MYController` to `myAction` whith this structure

```
[HttpGet]
[HttpPut]
[HttpPost]
[HttpDelete]
[HttpPatch]
public async Task<bool> myAction(string id)
{}
```

this route sends all types of requests that goes to `mydomain.com/myId` to this action. Now I want to get these requests too.

```
e.g.  mydomain.com/myId/myId2
e.g.  mydomain.com/myId/myId2?name=foo
e.g.  mydomain.com/myId/myId2/myId3
```

How should I change my route?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you. But your previous answer does not work. I also tried `template: "{id:length(8)}/{*params}"` and `template: "{id:length(8)}/{params?}"` with `public async Task<bool> myAction(string id, string params)`

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want to implement both rest and query parameter routing ?

Comment: yes. rest parameters and query parameters, should accept both.

Comment: @DreamMaker and what is the result of this `myAction(string id, string params)`?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I tried `template: "{id:length(8)}/{*params}"` and `template: "{id:length(8)}/{params?}"` but did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? Any errors? empty value of parameters? anything else? How should we know what works and what doesn't work? You need to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need

Comment: @RomanMarusyk When I use those routes, all the requests go to just this action and some other parts of my application do not work. On the other hand, the parameters which come to this action are wrong parameters. I need to get the requests that start with an id of 8 charachters and every thing could be in the rest of the request. Please let me know if you need me to explain more.

Comment: *“When I use those routes, all the requests go to just this action”* – Of course, because now every route `/foo/bar` is part of that route where `foo` and `bar` are just parameter values. You will need to make sure that the default route is configured first so that your new route will only catch the remainders. You should also consider making the route more unique again by adding a prefix.

Comment: @poke Thank you, that was a really good point. I moved that to the end of the routes and defined 2 different routes for other actions. It solved my problem. after all used this route `routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "senddata",
                    template: "{id:length(8)}/{*myparam}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Endpoint", action = "SendData" });`